# IntelliJ autocomplete taking very long for one object

Tags: intellij-idea

I have this one object, and in which ever file I use it, the autocomplete window takes suddenly very long (30 seconds) time. Autocomplete for all other objects are being loaded same as before.

Comment: This is probably a question for the IntellIj support team. You can try referring to this article: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems

Comment: Try to temporarily [disable](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html) all third-party plugins and update the IDE to the latest version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download . If the problem remains capture a CPU snapshot as described per the link provided by Sam (see the part "The CPU usage is high or IDE is slow" ) and raise a new issue at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new